# How to stop react component from going past the top of the page when scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

I want to make it do that when a user scrolls down a page, one of my react components reaches the top of the page, and stays there, not going any further up.

Imgur link to 'intranet' app im building: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uq5e2.jpg

In the image, the component with the thick red border should stay at the top of the page when scrolling, with a margin. Tried fixing position, but I don't want it static, just not scrollable past the top of the page.

*There are other similar questions, but none that seem to tackle this particular problem exactly - please correct me if I'm wrong.*

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the `sticky` position in css.

A sticky element toggles between relative and fixed, depending on the scroll position. It is positioned relative until a given offset position is met in the viewport - then it "sticks" in place (like position:fixed).

```css
.component {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

ref: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp

Comment: While this is exactly what i want to do, my app is using the overflow property which i can't get rid of, and which makes sticky not work. Need another way to do this...